# How to grant some user in Linux to modify hosts file

Tags: linux, hosts

Now I want to provide a function in our system to modify the system hosts file in Linux, but the user who runs the system is not root nor in root group.
Is there a way to grant a user the modification right on system hosts files? (without add this user into root)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set user as sudoer (user with more rights) you must edit /etc/sudoers. 
Type "sudo nano /etc/sudoers" and add your user with granted permition!

You need to add the following line to the sudoers file - for example:

user ALL=/etc/hosts  --user has right to modify hosts file

where user needs to be changed to real username of that user.

Comment: Use `visudo` if you're editing your sudoers file, since it will do syntax-checking and prevent you from accidentally ruining your `sudoers` file (as I have done in the past).

Comment: I set as you said, but I still can not save the hosts file in command line. It still prompt that it is read-only. I think sudo can grant user on this file, but some other place let me open this file in just read-only mode.

Comment: You should use chmod command to give permssion to write to file

Answer (score 0):

Your safest bet is to write a program that modifies the file in a controlled way and then grant the permission to run that program to the selected users using `sudo`.

Or you could also use ACLs: `setfacl/getfacl`.

Comment: And how would they go about doing this in this context?

Comment: I get a "Read-only file system" error trying to grant permissions to `/etc/hosts` with `setfacl`.